# How to convert Streaming audio format to make it work on ios

Tags: iphone, ios, core-audio

I am looking for a way to convert an .ogg extension audio streaming link so it works on iOS.

I want to convert the Audio in real time and get it played over the iphone.

Here is an example: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/b5/Radiohead_-_Pyramid_Song_%28sample%29.ogg

I am using https://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer this code for POC regarding this task. Please suggest me some way how can I achieve this.

Comment: Have you heard about Core Audio? This might be the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mpmovieviewcontroller player is good example for download streaming data and then play also same data.

You have to search it and implement it.it is working fine for me.